# Apache Ignite's Support for Sequences

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Does ignite support creating sequences? What is the equivalent of this statement in ignite?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.id_seq1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SQL sequences are not supported, you can check [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl) what DDL operations could be done in Ignite. Apache Ignite doesn't need to support all auxiliary DDL objects like `SEQUENCE` or `AGGREGATE` but is rather focused on `TABLE` and `INDEX` definitions, and the way you access your data using DML or `SELECT` queries instead.
- You can use [Atomic Sequence](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/atomic-sequence) as an alternative.